# Change editor for OpenShift to Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, kubernetes, openshift

I need to change my proxy settings for OpenShift. Therefore I can edit them like:

```bash
oc edit proxy.config.openshift.io cluster
```

Now, I don't want to use `edit` but rather VS Code. I found that [changing the editor](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/cli_reference/openshift_cli/developer-cli-commands.html#oc-edit) should be possible via:

```bash
KUBE_EDITOR="nano" oc edit svc/docker-registry
```

But when I try instead the following to use explicitly VS Code:

```bash
KUBE_EDITOR="code" oc edit svc/docker-registry
```

VS Code gets opened with an empty file and I can read the following on the command line as output: `Edit cancelled, no changes made.` Actually it looks like that output is printed before Code is opened.

Why is that? How can I get Code to edit my OpenShift files?

Edit: I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, `oc version` gives:

```bash
$ oc version
Client Version: 4.12.5
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: 4.12.5
Kubernetes Version: v1.25.4+a34b9e9
```

Comment: Have you tried [OpenShift Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-openshift-connector) ?

Comment: First few results in google show `KUBE_EDITOR="code -w"` (or `--wait`), I assume to ensure the command knows that edit is still on-going or it's finished. Did you try that? Also, you should list your system.

Comment: @Destroy666 that works perfect. Thanks. If you could put this into an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to define that env var for Visual Studio Code is:

```
KUBE_EDITOR="code -w"
```

`-w` (`--wait`) flag is used to notify the process that an edit is going on and it should wait until it's finished. See [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options) for more info.